# Find the conditional expectation of $Y$ given that $X=x$

Tags: probability, statistics

> Suppose $X,Y$ have a joint density of $f(x,y)=2$ for $x,y>0$ and $x+y\le1$. Find the conditional expectation of $Y$ given that $X=x$.

I know that and understand:

$f_X(x)=2(1-x)$

$f(Y|X=x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$

But I don't understand how $E(Y|X=x)=\frac{1-x}{2}$

Can someone explain?

Comment: Well, what happened when you tried to compute it? Perhaps, you made a mistake—and if you show this work someone could spot it and illuminate the issue.

Comment: I think I've figure it out. This is from my notes and I didn't have any working.

Comment: I thought it was supposed to be $E(Y|X=x)=\int_0^{1-x}y \frac{1}{1-x} dy = \frac{1-x}{2}$
But it's not

Comment: Nevermind, the integral I've stated above is correct, the website I was using (Symbolab) was acting weird

Comment: relying on a website to compute integrals for you? >.< Clearly, your problem isn’t with the definitions of concepts introduced in probability but with the required computations of calculus that go with them. If you want probability to become easier then review and practice integration—it is far more difficult to learn a new subject when you are weak with the prerequisites. Good luck with the studies :)

Comment: I have an exam soon and am just trying to review concepts quickly